# Stop python turtle with keypress

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to get the turtle to stop moving forward when I press the escape key. When I press escape, nothing happens! Can anyone tell me why? A solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()

running = True

def stop():
        running = False
        print(running)

while running:
        turtle.forward(1)
        screen.onkey(stop, "Esc")
        screen.listen()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems with your code.  The primary one is a missing `global` statement in `stop()`.  Secondary ones include: mixing the turtle function and object APIs; using key name 'Esc' instead of 'Escape'; putting `onkey()` and `listen()` in a loop; and potentially blocking events with your `while` loop.

I believe this code should do what you want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

running = True

def stop():
    global running

    running = False

def run():
    if running:
        turtle.forward(1)
        screen.ontimer(run)

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(stop, 'Escape')
screen.listen()

turtle = Turtle()

run()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.listen()
running = True

def stop():
        global running
        running = False

while running:
        turtle.forward(1)
        screen.onkey(fun=stop, key="Up")
        screen.listen()
```

//There are some issues first u have to make use global keyword in stop function and second include screen.listen() function in turtle so that the GUI can identify which key u have entered